# How can i remove gap between two views if layout is defined as horizontally

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can i remove gap between two views if layout is defined as horizontally

I have define horizontally layout but want to remove gap which is coming as attached snapshot by using below code

[Attached snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1kIr.png)

How can i remove this gap or space ?

xml:-

```
<LinearLayout

        android:paddingTop="5.0dip"

        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
            android:id="@+id/main_wv"
            android:layout_width="200dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="-100dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
            android:id="@+id/main_wv1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="200dp"


            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
            android:id="@+id/main_wv2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"


            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what device are you trying to fit this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Linear Layout to Relative Layout.

I don't know why this Linear Layout gives gaps between views 
even though they are placed next to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace the fixed width given in layout_width attribute by wrap_content and remove the margins as follows :

<LinearLayout    
            android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
                android:id="@+id/main_wv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
                android:id="@+id/main_wv1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
                android:id="@+id/main_wv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
            android:id="@+id/main_wv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
            android:id="@+id/main_wv1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
            android:id="@+id/main_wv2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Replace this with your code, when you set view to get equal width then you jusst need to set weight

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the view width you set as 200dp cant satisfy for 2 views in your currently selected deivce so use this

```
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dip">

    <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
        android:id="@+id/main_wv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
        android:id="@+id/main_wv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.WheelView1
        android:id="@+id/main_wv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what device are you trying to run the app on?

Comment: I am running on moto g 4 plus

Comment: can you see the layout as needed in preview in studio ?

Comment: try adding diff background color so you could identiffy the layout is that the complete layout mentioned in question or a part?

Comment: or set ad wrap content and add padding for each

Comment: after changing background color nothing is appearing

Comment: sorry i couldn't help i get the complete layout

Comment: also try changing the WheelView1 and use a view or space or textview and check and see if layout is visible or not